# Quantum Group Calculations in Mathematica

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, computer-algebra

I'm trying to learn how to do algebraic manipulations in Mathematica but not finding the help very helpful. I'm going to ask about a specific quantum group example related to a previous  question of mine. For $SU_q(N)$, how would I use Mathematica to show that
$$
S(u^1_2)u^3_1 = q^{-1}u^3_1S(u^1_2).
$$
I am, of course, assuming that such a thing can be done in Mathematica. If I am wrong in this assumption, could someone please direct me a package that can do this calculation? Gap, Magma?

Comment: It can be done, with a non trivial amount of work. I have only managed to do this in situations where there is a PBW basis available, though. I'll post here an example of how one can deal with the (simpler!) Weytl algebra later.

Comment: Scott Morrison has written an excellent quantum groups package in mathematica. Contact him at Scott tqft net and he can tell you more.

Comment: The GAP package Quagroup does computations with quantum groups.  See http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/quagroup.html

Comment: @Mariano-Suarez-Alvarez, PWB basis = what?

Answer (score 7):

I just found the link to the *QuantumGroups* Mathematica package by Scott Morrison mentioned by Noah:

http://katlas.org/wiki/QuantumGroups%60

Comment: This package just seems to deal with quantized enveloping algebras. Is there an equivalent version for quantized coordinate algebras?

Comment: @John McCarthy: I don't know.